# How to make global views.py for the entire Django app

Tags: django

I don't know if it's right to call it a global views.py, but what I'm trying to do is to get data for my navigation bar since the navigation bar has a search field supporting auto completes.

As the navigation bar shows up on any page of the website, I want to call the data for the search bar only once. Is that possible? I'm not sure because usually each Django app has its own views.py and those views.py is called as their app is called through their urs.py.

Comment: It's unclear for me what you're asking. Are you passing data to template or what?

Comment: You could add a views.py file or a templates directory to your project folder and not within an app, sure.

Answer (score 0):

You should use template inheritence for showing your search bar everywhere on the website, and a global url config to respond to search queries.

> The most powerful – and thus the most complex – part of Django’s template engine is template inheritance. Template inheritance allows you to build a base “skeleton” template that contains all the common elements of your site and defines blocks that child templates can override.

See [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) for more information